# Setting a skinState of a button in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, adobe

I want to set (manually) the skinState (for example 'disabled') of a button (that I skinned) in ActionScript.

For example:
I have a button skin with hostComponent: components.backend.btnMenuBakComp
The button skin has the default button states (up, over, down, ...), but I want to set one of this skinStates in ActionScript.

For example:

```
subMenu.btnDashboard.currentState = "disabled";
```

This doesn't work because the state "disabled" is not known in the component (it is only known in the skinState of btnDashboard).

How can I fix this?
Is there another solution then load a new skinClass?

Thanks

Comment: You're talking about the Button component in the components box right? Not the Button symbol type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick and dirty**

You can access the skin of any component and just set its state directly:

```
subMenu.btnDashboard.skin.currentState = "disabled";
```

That is however not a very clean way to do it. You are telling a Skin class directly what to do and completely bypassing the host component. Hence the host component has no idea of the changes that were made to its skin.

**The proper way**

A cleaner way to approach this is to expose a property on the host component and then tell the skin to adjust itself to possible changes by overriding the `getCurrentSkinState()` method.

You could for instance create a property 'enabled' and then tell the skin to update its state by calling `invalidateSkinState()` whenever 'enabled' is being set.

```
public function set enabled(value:Boolean):void {
    _enabled = value;
    invalidateSkinState();
}
```

Calling `invalidateSkinState()` will make the skin call `getCurrentSkinState()` in the next render cycle. This method will then look something like this:

```
override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String {
    return _enabled ? "normal" : "disabled";
}
```

Do note that since you are skinning a Button (or a subclass of it) all that I've written here is already baked into that component. So the answer to your question might be as simple as : "just set the 'enabled' property to `true`.

```
subMenu.btnDashboard.enabled = true;
```